# Is this an abbreviated form?

Tags: coordination

> "Harry Potter, do you know what unicorn blood is used for?" 
>       "No," said Harry, startled by the odd question. "We've only used the horn and tail hair in Potions." 
>       "That is because it is a monstrous thing, to slay a unicorn," said Firenze. "Only one who has nothing to lose, and **everything to
>   gain**, would commit such a crime. The blood of a unicorn will keep
>   you alive, even if you are an inch from death, but at a terrible
>   price. You have slain something pure and defenseless to save yourself,
>   and you will have but a half-life, a cursed life, from the moment the
>   blood touches your lips."  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is the bold part the short form of ‘one who has everything to gain’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an instance of a conjunct constituent rather than an ellipsis (conjunction reduction); that is, I would parse it as:

> ... one who has [<sup>Direct Object</sup> [<sub>NP</sub> nothing to lose] **and** [<sub>NP</sub> everything to gain] ] ...

The presence of the comma bracket around *and everything to gain* do give some support to the notion that this is a reduced supplemental clause:

> ... one [who has nothing to lose], and [<sub>who (also) has</sub> everything to gain ]

But I'm inclined to read those commas as rhetorical rather than syntactical: they delineate the rising emphasis, as if to say:

> ... one who has [ <sup>NOT MERELY</sup> [nothing to lose] <sup>BUT ALSO</sup> [everything to gain ] ]... *or*
>
> ... one who has <sup>BOTH</sup> [ [nothing to lose] AND [everything to gain] ]

Comment: So you mean ‘nothing to lose’ and ‘everything to gain’ are the two sides of the same coin?

Comment: @Listenever W e l l . . . They don't *necessarily* imply each other. A specific action might offer you nothing to lose, but nothing to gain either, and vice versa. But they are often spoken of together, so it's practically a [fixed phrase]https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nothing+to+lose+and+everything+to+gain%22&oq=%22nothing+to+lose+and+everything+to+gain%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.8823j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Anyway, I read this as *syntactically* = "one who has [A&B]" rather than "one [who has A] and [who has B]". As kiam says, "[one who has A] and [one who has B]" is Right Out.

Comment: What do you think 'everything to gain' is a supplementive as a noun phrase or a verbless phrase (=small clause), meaning 'everything is to gain'

Comment: @Listenever This is another instance of the *HAVE X to VERB* construction discussed in your [earlier question](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nothing+to+lose+and+everything+to+gain%22&oq=%22nothing+to+lose+and+everything+to+gain%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.8823j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). You could paraphrase it as "one who expects to lose nothing and gain everything".

Comment: I find this answer correct but overly technical for an ELL person. As a linguist, I appreciate it but if I were learning English, I would not understand it.

Comment: @Lambie If you check this poster's history you will find that she had a very sophisticated understanding of technical grammar.

Comment: @StoneyB I am not in the habit of checking poster's histories. I still think a simpler explanation is possible, which is what I have given.

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing that sentence with more words, you get:

> Only one who has nothing to lose, and **has** everything to gain, would commit such a crime.

The sentence is speaking of a person who has nothing to lose and has everything to gain. You should not rephrase it as follows:

> Only one who has nothing to lose, and **one who has** everything to gain, would commit such a crime.

In this case, the sentence seems speaking of two different people.

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions are: to have nothing to lose and to have everything to gain [from some action]. The first: /to have nothing to lose/ by doing some X is heard very frequently in English. The second one is heard less frequently but is also common.

That said, putting them together is also a standard form of expression, they, in effect, can be seen as "going together" but in this order: **to have nothing to lose one first, followed by the everything to gain**.

They can, however, be used separately and on their own: He has everything to gain by being a nice guy.

To answer your question about /Only one who has nothing to lose, and everything to gain, would commit such a crime nothing to lose, and everything to gain./

Yes, it is a shortened form. And a general rule in English is that you do not have to repeat a verb to create a full second subject and predicate when it is obvious.

a) She has a huge amount of property and little money. = b) She has a huge amount of property and she has little money.

a) and b) mean the same thing. Grammatically, they are different: a) has a compound object and b) is a compound sentence.